# The instance of entity type 'SalesOrder' cannot be tracked because another instance of this type with the same key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using .net core.

> ***My Goal:*** I want to be able `Edit` a SalesOrder just after `Creating`.

Right now I am able to Create and Edit. But it is throwing an error

> The instance of entity type 'SalesOrder' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance of this type with the same key is already being
>   tracked. When adding new entities, for most key types a unique
>   temporary key value will be created if no key is set (i.e. if the key
>   property is assigned the default value for its type). If you are
>   explicitly setting key values for new entities, ensure they do not
>   collide with existing entities or temporary values generated for other
>   new entities. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one
>   entity instance with a given key value is attached to the context.

When I try editing just after creating.

My Save() function:

```
public class SalesOrdersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;
    public SalesOrdersController(ApplicationDbContext dbContext){
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    // ...other Controller actions
    public JsonResult Save([FromBody]SalesOrderViewModel salesOrderViewModel)
    {
        SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
        salesOrder.document_id = salesOrderViewModel.document_id;
        salesOrder.customer = salesOrderViewModel.customer;
        salesOrder.document_status_id = salesOrderViewModel.document_status_id;
        ...
        salesOrder.object_state = salesOrderViewModel.object_state;

        _dbContext.Entry(salesOrder).State = Helpers.ConvertState(salesOrder.object_state);
        _dbContext.SaveChanges();

        salesOrderViewModel.document_id = salesOrder.document_id;
        salesOrderViewModel.object_state = ObjectState.Unchanged;
        return Json(new { salesOrderViewModel });
    }
}
```

And a function to update states depending on the request:

```
public static EntityState ConvertState(ObjectState objectState){
    switch (objectState){
        case ObjectState.Added:
            return EntityState.Added;
        case ObjectState.Modified:
            return EntityState.Modified;
        case ObjectState.Deleted:
            return EntityState.Deleted;
        default:
            return EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}
```

I understand that it is a problem with refreshing the entity state just after creating. How can I resolve that error?

Comment: `salesOrder.document_id = salesOrderViewModel.document_id;` Why are you explicitly setting the ID? It looks like you're trying to set it to an ID the Entity Framework is already knows, thus the error. Any reason not to just auto-generate the ID? The error tells your pretty explicitly what the problem is.

Comment: @Basic, I am using a ViewModel. Something to note: Save() is being used to Create, Update and Delete. So I have to assign the document_id from the ViewModel before saving and it is not considered when creating. But that ain't the problem.

Comment: why is your viewmodel part of your context? that's highly unlikely. anyways, you should probably return to a unit of work pattern and use a different context for reading data than you used for writing the same data. As entry() WILL attach the object as a whole, but SaveChanges() clears the ChangeTracker, but not the context entries, you'll have to clear your context all the time otherwise - of which I'm not actually sure if it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

You said you understand the problem... so the solution is to get the original entity from the database and update its properties directly and then update it itself. I mean what you need to do is to avoid calling

```
    context.Update(entity);
```

Where entity is the object in your model.

So One solution would be something like the following which I agree it may not the best way of solving it.

Let's assume you are using generic repository (which is harder than non generic because you do not know the fields beforehand)

```
public void Edit(TBusinessObject entity)
        {

        var originalEntity = context.Set<TBusinessObject>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id.Equals(entity.Id));
        EntityEntry<TBusinessObject> original = context.Entry(originalEntity);
        EntityEntry<TBusinessObject> client = context.Entry(entity);
        foreach (var property in original.OriginalValues.Properties)
        {
            var dbMember = original.Member(property.Name);
            var clientMember = client.Member(property.Name);
            if(!property.IsPrimaryKey() && dbMember.CurrentValue != clientMember.CurrentValue && clientMember.CurrentValue!= null)
            {
                dbMember.CurrentValue = clientMember.CurrentValue;
                dbMember.IsModified = true;
            }
        }
        context.Update(originalEntity);
        context.SaveChanges(true);
    }
```

Again, This code could be optimized and it would be way simpler if it was not a generic repository, where you know the names and the types of the fields.

Update 1:
I found out that EF.Core although not yet fully fledged with all the features that were supported by EF6. Yet it is somehow leaned towards the modern development practices..  The example that you posted was all about using EF.Core to implement the traditional repository mentality. If you switch to use UnitOfWork or CQRS you will not face these problems, changes like updates and CRUS in general will be smooth like never before. I am passing an object to the context, and the context itself is able to figure out to what table it belongs and how to handle it. Therefore I recommend changing the way you choose to utilize EF.Core

Try this simplest implementation:

```
public void Commit()
{
    using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
            context.UpdateRange(Changed);
            context.AddRange(Added);
            context.RemoveRange(Deleted);

            context.SaveChanges();
            ClearAllChanges();
    }
}
```

Where "Changed, Added, Deleted" are just lists where you might consider AsynchronousBags

Comment: *avoid calling `context.Update(entity);`* -- so why `context.Update(originalEntity);`? Why get the original object with `AsNoTracking()`? Even then, it's not clear how all this would solve the original problem because it only deals with individual entities. OP's problem is likely to be caused by `salesOrder.customer` containing references to other instances of `SalesOrders` having the same primary key.

Comment: Even if the Order class has nothing to do with the Customers, this error did exist. It might be a bug with EFCore.